# Foreign key constraint in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a row in a table. But when I try to delete I am getting an error foreign key constraint. This is what I tried

```
candlepin=# delete from cp_upstream_consumer where uuid = 'd7f7eb37-ac39-44d5-80ba-7f606';
ERROR:  update or delete on table "cp_upstream_consumer" violates foreign key constraint "fk_upstream_consumer_id" on table "cp_owner"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(021308a278d03bc50178da42c1a402bd) is still referenced from table "cp_owner".
candlepin=#
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And what kind of help do you need? First delete records from child table/tables then from the parent

Comment: My requirement is to delete the row in cp_upstream_customer. But I when I do, I am getting the above error

Comment: At least one row in `cp_owner` is referencing the rows you want to delete from `cp_upstream_consumer` - you need to first delete those rows in `cp_owner`